# Cube.js issue Error: npm install --save-dev @cubejs-backend/cubestore-driver failed with exit code 1

Tags: npm, cube.js

I have a problem with my first Cube.js project.
After the creation with the classic cmd

- cubejs create hello-world -d postgres
  I hav this error message:

> @cubejs-backend/cubestore@0.26.43 postinstall
> C:\Users\utente\hello-world\node_modules@cubejs-backend\cubestore if
> [[ -z "${CUBESTORE_SKIP_POST_INSTALL}" ]]; then node
> ./dist/post-install.js; else echo "Skipping Cube Store Post
> Installing"; fi
>
> -z non atteso. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING
> OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted
> {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR!
> @cubejs-backend/cubestore@0.26.43 postinstall: `if [[ -z "${CUBESTORE_SKIP_POST_INSTALL}" ]]; then node ./dist/post-install.js; else echo "Skipping Cube Store Post Installing"; fi` npm ERR! Exit
> status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
> @cubejs-backend/cubestore@0.26.43 postinstall script. npm ERR! This is
> probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
> output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-04T09_11_07_064Z-debug.log
>
> Cube.js Error ---------------------------------------
>
> Error: npm install --save-dev @cubejs-backend/cubestore-driver failed
> with exit code 1
> at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cubejs-cli\src\utils.ts:14:16)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cubejs-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug (regression caused after rewriting post-install handler), fixed in v0.26.48.

Thanks